# What does this code do for Paypal?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, core

I am currently trying to create a module for Magento to show if the payment method used is Paypal Express via credit card or via Paypal account.

Digging through the files I come accross app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php

There is a line in Request/response for GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails where the code is:

```
protected $_getRecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsResponse = array('STATUS', /* TODO: lot of other stuff */);
```

What does this code do?

Comment: It's simple, they will add some other stuff in future if needed.

Comment: Name suggest this function is intended to fetch or parse response from PayPal regarding recurring payments (subscriptions). I doubt it will be finished as Magento1 is currently only on bugfixes updates and since M2 is out no new functionalities are added. Lately they've postponed end-of-life for M1 and October 2018 is no longer the case but they did not retracted no new functionalities statement.

Comment: Well that's kind of vague and irresponsible for Magento.